# Send Verification Email When Updating Email Address in Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to send a verification email from Firebase Auth when an existing auth user is trying to UPDATE their email address. I want to do this before actually calling 'user.updateEmail(newEmail)' so that if they should not be using that email address for whatever reason, it doesn't actually change their email login in Firebase Auth.

It doesn't look like the 'sendEmailVerification' method allows for manually providing an email address to verify.

Ideally, I would like to do something like:

```
//User provides a newEmailAddress for their account

//Send verification email to the newEmailAddress

//User verifies newEmailAddress

user.updateEmail(newEmailAddress) is executed
```

Is there a graceful way to do this through Firebase Auth?

Comment: This appears to be possible now with verifyBeforeUpdateEmail https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#verifybeforeupdateemail but I haven't tested it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built into Firebase Authentication for this flow.

If you have your own email server, you can definitely implement it. But you will need to be comfortable generating your own nonces, sending email, and having an endpoint to handle the clicks in the email.

Comment: Aw, bummer.  Well, maybe some day... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Frank If there is no verification step, what are we supposed to do for users who accidentally enter an incorrect email address (even after a "confirm email adress" field on the frontend?)

Comment: If there's no email verification step, it doesn't matter that their email doesn't exist. But if you want to protect them from fat-fingered email addresses, you'll want to implement email verification *or* use a provider that has already verified their email address.

Comment: Is this a case for using something like sendgrid?

Comment: What about verifyBeforeUpdateEmail? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#verifybeforeupdateemail

Answer (score 2):

### October 2021

This is definitely possible with the `verifyBeforeUpdateEmail` method.

Example (Javascript):

```
firebase.auth().currentUser
  .verifyBeforeUpdateEmail('user@example.com')
  .then(function() {
    // Verification email sent. 
    // Clicking the link in email will update the email address.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Error occurred. Inspect error.code.
  });
```

^ The above code is all you need.

However you can also pass an optional second parameter `actionCodeSettings`. When this parameter is present, the state/continue URL will be set as the "continueUrl" parameter in the email verification link.

Example (Javascript):

```
const actionCodeSettings = {
  url: 'https://www.example.com/cart?email=user@example.com&cartId=123',
  iOS: {
    bundleId: 'com.example.ios'
  },
  android: {
    packageName: 'com.example.android',
    installApp: true,
    minimumVersion: '12'
  },
  handleCodeInApp: true
};
firebase.auth().currentUser.verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(
  'user@example.com', actionCodeSettings)
  .then(function() {
    // Verification email sent.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Error occurred. Inspect error.code.
  });
```

Firebase [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#verifybeforeupdateemail)

Comment: v9 `verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(user, 'newemail@example.com', actionCodeSettings);` https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#verifybeforeupdateemail

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way. You need to set `continueUrl` and call `verifyBeforeUpdateEmail`, which will redirect the user to your app. The DynamicLink will contain the required information for you to validate the process and you can call `updateEmail` after that.